# How to put log in and log out option in header beside cart in magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, login, menu, header, logout

I wants to change My Account to Log in Button in header beside cart option. 
when user made log in then it should show log out option in header.

Please tell me the code with path.

Answer (score 0):

Just going in app\design\frontend\rwd\default\template\page\html and open header.phtml file

Here you see top links div so just add below code for you login and logout.

```
<?php if (!Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()): ?>
<a href="<?php echo Mage::helper('customer')->getLoginUrl(); ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Login') ?></a>
<?php else: ?>
<a href="<?php echo Mage::helper('customer')->getLogoutUrl(); ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Logout') ?></a>
```

Just add above code in your theme header file. it's working.